# UISearchBar in UISearchController Does Not Disappear

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I AM NOT USING STORYBOARD SEGUES.

When I use `UISearchController` to have a search bar at the top of my table view, I get extremely strange behavior. Is there documentation on how I'm supposed to handle the search bar when a view dismisses? When I switch to a new view controller via an animation or push one on a nav stack, the bar is stuck in its spot until I hit the "Cancel" button.

See a video of what's happening in this short clip:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G7xFMENm_o&feature=youtu.be

This is the code, in the view controller, that sets up search bar:

```
var s: UISearchController!
private func configureSearching() {
    s = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    s.searchResultsUpdater = self
    s.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    s.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    s.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    tableView.tableHeaderView = s.searchBar
    s.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISearchController persisting after segue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472011/uisearchcontroller-persisting-after-segue)

Comment: I am not using `prepareForSegue:`

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference, read the documentation or [this](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/228)

Answer (score 0):

you should add the following line in viewDidLoad

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue.