# UISearchController doesn't hide view when pushed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController to display a search bar and results within a UITableView. I managed to set it up correctly, but when I search the results and then select one of the rows in the tableview, and push a new view controller to the navigation stack, I would expect the search bar to not be visible anymore. However, when I try this, the search bar from the first view controller is visible in the 2nd view controller:

```
    if (self.searchController == nil) {
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

One option is to call `self.searchController setActive:NO]` inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but there isn't a way to do this without the distracting animation of bringing down the search bar each time the search results are selected from.

Does anyone have the same problem? Is there a way to tell UISearchController to hide the search bar when pushed? It worked fine when I was using UISearchDisplayController

Comment: Does this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472011/uisearchcontroller-persisting-after-segue/29624748#29624748) help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Put this in your **caller's** viewDidLoad:

Swift:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Objective-C:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: What an obscure solution. But sure enough, it worked!

Comment: In the `viewDidLoad` of WHAT? The current or the target controller. But doesn't work in both cases anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what's more bizarre. The fact that it worked for you or the fact that it doesn't work for me.