# Hide search bar of search display controller

Tags: ios, hide, searchbar

I dragged a search bar and display controller to a view controller and placed it at the bottom of the outline.

I then set it to display in navigation bar with following line in viewdidload.  All that works.

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;
```

However, I want to hide it initially, and the following line in vewdidload is not having any effect.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = true;
```

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I think I have figured out that you cannot have searchBar.hidden = true and displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar at the same time.  Which is fine by me as I only want one or the other.  So I tried separating the two cases.

First in view did load, I put

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = true;
```

This does work if by itself.

Then I have a search button wired to an action method as follows:

```
 - (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"search button pressed");
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = false;
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

However, while I can see from the log that the method is called, it does not unhide the search bar.  Perhaps it is delegate issue but still looking for solutions.

Comment: Do you only want to hide the searchBar? Then `searchBar.hidden = true`is enough.

Comment: That gives me use of undeclared identifier

Comment: Check the answer, if you´re having trouble adding the outlet just post a comment to my post and I´ll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

1. Add an outlet to your searchBar from your Storyboard
2. Then you can use the outlet identifier to hide the searchBar by adding the following row

`searchBar.hidden = true`

Comment: I created the outlet but it does not seem to toggle the search bar on and off i.e. true or false does not seem to have any effect.  Perhaps I should create an outlet for the searchDisplayController and try to toggle it?

Comment: You could try that, but that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

=> try it.

self.definesPresentationContext = true

OR-------------

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

=> more If You Want to know given Refrence below might be useful:-

[How to implement UISearchController in UITableView - SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664315/how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-in-uitableview-swift?rq=1)

[UISearchController doesn't hide view when pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937275/uisearchcontroller-doesnt-hide-view-when-pushed)