# UINavigationController transition issue

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

This is a Apple simple guide about **Table Search with UISearchController**, and I have downloaded the demo project and it is working well.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

I want to have transparent navigation bar on product detail view (**DetailViewController.swift**). After changing some behaviors I have transition issue when going back from product detail to device list with swipe gesture(Video link below).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/denqomhhxasxv58/issue.mov?dl=0

For transparent navigation bar I have added this lines on **DetailViewController** 
**viewWillAppear** method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // ...

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
}
```

In **MainTableViewController.swift** I have added this code to make navigationBar default style.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

---

Also I made changes on MainTableViewController **viewDidLoad** method and sets this properties to true.

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
```

So my problem is to fix that issue. Anyone can help me?

Update:

Swipe transition from product detail to device list
[image: Swipe transition from product detail to device list]
Search controller active state when product detail not opened
[image: Search controller active state when product detail not opened]
Search controller active state after product detail opened
[image: Search controller active state after product detail opened]

Comment: Have you tried to hide the search bar on transition?

Comment: @Jake this is not a good idea, I have tried but no any native method found to hide navigationItem searchBar

Comment: This tells you how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619247/9333764

Comment: Thanks @Jake, but that solution not solved my transition issue, I have tried)

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Do you successfully solved it?